# Forms in canvas apps get redirected to the canvas URL with code parameter in querystring in latest Chrome

Tags: facebook, html, forms, google-chrome, facebook-apps

I strange issue started happening to my app in Chrome (latest - 29.0.1547.57) on Mac. When I submit forms, I get redirected to the app's canvas URL with the "code" parameter in my query string. As far as I remember, this happens only when the user authorizes the app?

This is the form tag:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="detail.php" method="post" id="edit-form">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="create.php" method="post" id="create-form" target="_self">
```

Seems to me like it started happening only after I updated Chrome. I tried on my WIN laptop  with Chrome 28.0.1500.95 and 29.0.1547.57 and all worked fine though. Maybe only some issues with my browser?

Comment: try loading that browser with out plugins, or do a fresh install.

Comment: fresh install helped, thanks... should have tired it before :)

Comment: you may not have even figured that out until you tried for help, so no time wasted, no harm done.